# Sitecore 8 Experience Editor: Breadcrumb path name only one language version

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore8, experience-editor

Before moving on to Sitecore 8, Sitecore 7 used to show the breadcrumb in both German as well as in English, as selected in Experience tab. But now in Sitecore 8 this is not happening.The breadcrumb path is shown in German no matter language changed in Experience tab.

In Sitecore 8: [image]  for English

InSitecore 7: [image]  for English

I am not sure what is causing this and where to look or start looking.
All help appreciated

Comment: Do you have any custom code relating to setting the language?

Comment: No. i dont. Also i checked the speak-->breadcrumb.js but i couldnt find any issue.

Comment: Is the item name in German? Have you changed the option to show item name instead of display name?

Comment: No...it shows display name but in German. Neways..item name is in English so it should have taken "home" instead but its not.

Comment: What is your client language, for the user you have logged in?

Comment: English. I have configured the client language as per cookies. So if you have selected Eng earlier then it takes Eng.